# Centering \dot in a symbol macro (\listofsymbol)

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, subscripts, xstring

I was trying to achieve the results of get a variable listed in `listofsymbol`'s generated list, when called with a `-dot` suffix. If was trying also to find a way to center `dot` in variables with subscript (without using subscript listing capabilities of the package).

To do that a macro `\checkUnderscore` was implemented, that tries to find `_` character in a string, split and insert the command before the subscript.

But if the macro has a `\mathbf` directive, the dot is printed in the extreme left of the variable.

I cannot find a solution for this behavior, but i think it is an error in my macro. Do you have any idea? **thank's in advance**.

*A minimal example:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}

\newcommand{\checkUnderscore}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{_}{\dot{\StrBefore{#1}{_}}_{\StrBehind{#1}{_}}}{\dot{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@createsym}[3]
{\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\relax\ensuremath{#3}\spaceaftersym\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#2isused\endcsname {yes}} %evntl. gdef
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2doc\endcsname}{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2tabdoc\endcsname}{\ensuremath{#3} & #1}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2isused\endcsname}{no}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2dot\endcsname}{\relax\ensuremath{\expandafter\checkUnderscore#3}\spaceaftersym\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#2isused\endcsname {yes}}}
\makeatother

\opensymdef
\newsym[Test A]{symA}{x}
\newsym[Test B]{symB}{x_{p}}
\newsym[Test C]{symC}{\mathbf{x}}
\newsym[Test D]{symD}{\mathbf{x}_{p}}
\closesymdef


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here's my symbol $\symAdot$, 
\item and the other one with subscript $\symBdot$,
\item and the other one bold $\symCdot$,
\item and the other bold one with subscript $\symDdot$,
\end{itemize}

\listofsymbols
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like your expansion is applying the dot to only the `\mathbf`, not to what it is applied to.  adding a second set of braces to `\newsym[Test C]{symC}{{\mathbf{x}}}` only results in an unhelpful error message.  what you want to get as the expanded forms is `\dot{\mathbf{x}}` and `\dot{\mathbf{x}}_{p}` (note that *only* the bolded "x" should have the dot applied).  but how you would parse that i'm not prepared to explore.

Comment: Yes you understood the problem, but is more likely dot is applied to an empty object (`\dot{}\mathbf{x}_p`), not to only `\mathbf`. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing `\dot` in front of your object works in all your cases, just don't add extra brackets.  The underscore testing is unnecessary.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@createsym}[3]
{\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\relax\ensuremath{#3}\spaceaftersym\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#2isused\endcsname {yes}} %evntl. gdef
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2doc\endcsname}{#1}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2tabdoc\endcsname}{\ensuremath{#3} & #1}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2isused\endcsname}{no}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname#2dot\endcsname}{\relax
\ensuremath{\dot #3}\spaceaftersym\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#2isused\endcsname {yes}}}
\makeatother

\opensymdef
\newsym[Test A]{symA}{x}
\newsym[Test B]{symB}{x_{p}}
\newsym[Test C]{symC}{\mathbf{x}}
\newsym[Test D]{symD}{\mathbf{x}_{p}}
\closesymdef


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here's my symbol $\symAdot$, 
\item and the other one with subscript $\symBdot$,
\item and the other one bold $\symCdot$,
\item and the other bold one with subscript $\symDdot$,
\end{itemize}

\listofsymbols
\end{document}
```